# Can we have an "edit question" magic link for answer comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits, magic-links

Yet another request for a magic link. In the following situations:

1. I answer a question, the asker replies to me in a comment, and I want to reply to them asking them to edit certain information into the question
2. The asker adds extra information as an answer instead of an edit

I want to give the user a link to `[edit]` the **question**, not the current answer I'm commenting on.

Can we have a magic link like `[edit/question]` (or `[edit/q]`) that:

- becomes the word edit
- is a link to the parent question of the answer the comment is posted to?

I find myself wishing I had this link about as much as I use the link to `[edit]` the current question.

Comment: You might be interested in my [Custom “magic links” for comments](http://stackapps.com/q/6650/26088) userscript